# How to open UIViewControllers and keepstate without NavgationController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 views in my application.

I would like to know how to properly open and load views when buttons are clicked.

Currently when a button is clicked from the first view I open the second view like this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    getPLViewController = [[GetPLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetPLViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [keyWindow addSubview:getProjectListViewController.view];

    [self presentViewController:getPLViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And now that the second view is open I open the third like this

```
currentPLViewController = [[CurrentPLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentPLViewController" bundle:nil];


UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWindow addSubview: currentPLViewController.view];

[self presentViewController:currentPLViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I have no idea if this is correct anymore as I have been having trouble with the view showing up on its side if I try to load it before the previous view has finished loading or something along those lines.

This is how I go back from a viewcontroller

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

So I would like to know is this a correct way of doing it? or is there a better way?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use a UINavigationController on your root view ?

You can hide the navigation bar and it will be cleaner and it will match with the Apple guidelines to push views.

Supposing you use XIB.
When you add your first view from the `AppDelegate`, add an `UINavigationController` and hide this one :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Next on your `RootViewController` (first view) you add a button and push the `SecondViewController` :

```
- (IBAction)displaySecondView
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The same in your `SecondViewController` to push the third one :

```
- (IBAction)displayThirdView
{
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController thirdViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and an action to back to the previous view :

```
- (IBAction)back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: okay say for instant I am on the first view but I want to jump to the thrid view?

Comment: so add `- (IBAction)displayThirdView` in your first view :)

Comment: okay cool Im gong to figure this all out and I will let you know how I get on :)

Comment: grr.. i just ticked and unticked you sorry.. but now my rootview is on its side. I have set it to landscape orientation only. the status bar is landscape but the view is portrat.. ?!

Comment: It's an another problem here ^^ you need to set up the orientation in your project `deployment info` and choose landscape left et landscape right