# How to load and unload a UIViewController from the window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have create some logic when the app is loaded that I can load from 3 different views depending on some values I set in my plist.

This is what my code looks like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //sets context for coredata
    CoreDataController *coreDataController = [CoreDataController sharedManager];
    coreDataController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    PrefsController *prefsController = [[PrefsController alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *prefsDictionary = [prefsController readPrefs];

    NSLog(@"%@", prefsDictionary);

    NSString *projectListBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"ProjectListAvailable"];
    NSString *installsBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"InstallsAvailable"];
    NSString *finishinBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"FinishingAvailable"];


    if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"])) {
        self.getProjectListViewController = [[GetProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.getProjectListViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"])) {
        self.currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.currentProjectListViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I would like to be able to then load and unload UIViewControllers (including removing from memory by using buttons presses etc.

I dont want to use a navigaiton based controller as I want the views to be static or individual if that makes more sense.

If someone could show me some example code to load a new UIViewController to the window and remove the old UIViewController that would be greatly apprecaited.

However I am not sure of the correct was to handle this, or even how the code looks.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should consider using navigationcontrollers to handle your navigation through the app.. These will make sure the loadView en unloadView of your viewcontrollers will be called automatically. I cannot imagine another way then this to be the correct way. Buttons can be used to push these viewcontrollers on the navigationcontroller and thus create a navigation to the view.

Comment: I'm agree with @TotumusMaximus. I think the best way is to have a rootViewController in your main window and push the others views with a navigation controller.
Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241205/how-to-open-uiviewcontrollers-and-keepstate-without-navgationcontroller/19242113#19242113

Comment: I would tend to agree with you guys, however its not a navigation centric app. there are 3 views all of which have importance at any one time. Hence the app delegate being able to load any of the 3 viewcontrollers as the first/rootvew.

Comment: I will add an answer soon for your without navigation controller ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, is not a good way to load your view like this.
It would be better to load a rootViewController in your AppDelegate and add your current view depending of your plist inside the `RootViewController` :

**AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

After in your `RootViewController` add a subview of the current view depending on your plist :

**RootViewController.m**

```
#pragma mark - View management
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *prefsDictionary = [prefsController readPrefs];

    NSLog(@"%@", prefsDictionary);

    NSString *projectListBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"ProjectListAvailable"];
    NSString *installsBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"InstallsAvailable"];
    NSString *finishinBoolString = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"FinishingAvailable"];

    if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"])) {
        self.getProjectListViewController = [[GetProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        // Add View Controller
        [self.view addSubview:self.getProjectListViewController.view
    }
    else if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"])) {
        self.currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        // Add View Controller
        [self.view addSubview:self.currentProjectListViewController.view];
    }
    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        // Add View Controller
        [self.view addSubview:self.viewController.view];
    }
}
```